# For 7 layer food forest what should be the sequence of plantation?

Tags: fruit-trees, food-crops, permaculture, sustainability

Location: Eastern India, West Bengal (Tropical Climate)

For the following layer, is there any prescribed sequence of plantation?

1. Canopy
2. Understory
3. Shrub
4. Herb
5. Ground cover
6. Climber
7. Root

## Questions

1. Can Canopy, Understory, Shrub, Herb be planted at the same time?
2. If not, what should be the correct order of plantation?

I am wondering, if Canopy is planted as the pioneer, will Understory and Shrub grow under its shade?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific and add the location of where you intend to plant this system? Permaculture's success is using local resources so location matters

Comment: @kevinskio thank you for your comment, I have updated the location. I understand for permaculture a lot depends on location and local availability. Could you help me understand how the processes, like order of plantation depends on location?

Comment: @Sarbottam  The plants you choose have different growth rates and characteristics and what you can plant depends on where you live.  On another note permaculture does not address using non native plants but I find the more plants you use that are native to your area the less surprises happen later